# use of type declaration defined in a templated c++ class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

What's the proper way to declare the `coord` variable in the example below? A template argument placeholder will work such as:

```
MyClass<int>::Coord coord;
```

That sure is ugly considering that `Coord` is completely agnostic of the template argument. Ideally, is there some syntax that would allow me to declare `coord` without specifying any template parameter?

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
 public:
  enum Coord {
    x, y, z,
  };  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MyClass<???>::Coord coord;
}
```

Comment: If it's completely agnostic of type why not move it out of class?

Comment: Either move it out of the class or keep `MyClass<int>::Coord coord;` but add a good comment line like `// using int because *some* type is required to use MyClass<T>::Coord`. Everything else is over-engineering IMO.

Comment: It's in the class because it's class-specific which goes for every type, method and ivar whether they require a template parameter or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to use `Coord` without a template type for `MyClass`, move it (and all the non-template stuff) from `MyClass` to a non-template base class. You'll be using it as:

```
MyBase::Coord coord;
```

and you'll get the following to equal to `true`:

```
std::is_same<MyClass<void>::Coord, MyClass<int>::Coord>::value
```

I don't know a case where you'd want it to be `false` for an `enum`, unless you want to specialize it.

Comment: Although that would work it seems far from ideal.  I want to design my class taxonomy based on the application domain and what should naturally be encapsulated rather than if templated or not.  If I have one templated ivar that I wish to set through a constructor in a class with N other methods and M other ivars what is the class hierarchy suppose to look like?

Comment: Thank you for this good answer.  Took me awhile to come around to this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
template <>
class MyClass<std::string> {
 public:
  static int Coord = 42;
};
```

What I hope to show you with this example is that specifying the template parameter actually **can** make a huge difference, even if `Coord` itself does not depend on it. Thus, if `Coord` really shouldn't depend on the template parameter (which seems to be the case here), then it shouldn't be a member of the template class in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Basically adding to what everyone else said, you should consider if it should be a class member at all, and if it should be, you should consider moving it to a base class.

Having said that, you can create the following code, which, while somewhat convoluted, will allow you to use

```
MyClass<>::Coord coord;
```

---

Start by defining a dummy class in a `detail` namespace:

```
namespace detail
{
    struct MyClassVoid{};
};
```

Now declare your class

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass;
```

and give it a specialization to the dummy class, in which you define the "non template" stuff:

```
template<>
class MyClass<detail::MyClassVoid>
{
public:
enum Coord {
    x, y, z,
}; 
};
```

Now define the general form of the class, deriving from the specialized one:

```
template <typename T=detail::MyClassVoid>
class MyClass : public MyClass<detail::MyClassVoid> {
    // "Real members" go here.
};
```

This will build:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
MyClass<>::Coord coord;
}
```

---

Full code:

```
namespace detail                                                                                                                            
{
    struct MyClassVoid{};
};

template <typename T>
class MyClass;


template<>
class MyClass<detail::MyClassVoid>
{
public:
enum Coord {
    x, y, z,
}; 
};


template <typename T=detail::MyClassVoid>
class MyClass : public MyClass<detail::MyClassVoid> {
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
MyClass<>::Coord coord;
}
```